# I am getting 504 gateway timeout error on server after upload 3.92 MB files in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, webclient

I am getting 504 gatewaytimeout error on server after upload 3.92 MB files

but record get inserted into table successfully

i have 1 webserver and 1 appserver

on Webserver:

- i am reading excel file and convert it into datable and save excel
  into another folder its hardly take 1 min 20 sec
- then i passed that datable to to appserver using following code

  sProposal = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
  UploadDetails x = await webAPIClient.CallWebAPI<UploadDetails, DataTable>(dataTable, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"].ToString());
  return x;
  });
  }

on Appserver

- i take datatable and pass into sqlbulkcopy and insert into table ,return with only success msg it hardly get few sec

Following is my web.config

```
<location path="upl">
   <system.web>
     <!--The default size is 4096 kilobytes (4 MB). MaxValue is 2147483647 KB (2 TB)-->
     <!-- 100 MB in kilobytes -->
     <httpRuntime excutionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
     <security>
       <requestFiltering>          
         <!--The default size is 30000000 bytes (28.6 MB). MaxValue is 4294967295 bytes (4 GB)-->
         <!-- 100 MB in bytes -->
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
       </requestFiltering>
     </security>
   </system.webServer>
 </location>
```

i also increase maxRequestLength,maxAllowedContentLength also but still it showing 504 gateway timeout on server

but record get inserted successfully (total 45,345 record)

What I have tried:

i also increase maxRequestLength,maxAllowedContentLength, and profile code which code take what time and all but still 504 error is coming